# Rails ActiveAdmin Eliminating n+1 queries on custom attributes belong to another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, performance, activeadmin

I'm using activeadmin for showing branch model records, the branch model has many branchphones, and I want to show the first branchphone created for this branch as an extra custom attribute on activeadmin branch model screen, so I wrote it like that

```
    show do
    attributes_table do
      row :id
      row :manager_name
      row :manager_email
      row :phone_number do |branch|
        branch&.branch_phones&.order(created_at: :asc)&.first&.phone_number
      end
    end
  end

  index do
    column :id
    column :manager_name
    column :manager_email
    column :phone_number do |branch|
      branch&.branch_phones&.order(created_at: :asc)&.first&.phone_number
    end
    actions
  end
```

the problem with that code is that it causes me n+1 queries, every time the code get a branch, it goes and create an extra query inside it to get the branch's branch phones, which results on something like that when calling the branch model screen on activeadmin

```
Processing by Admin::BranchesController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"subdomain"=>""}
  AdminUser Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "admin_users".* FROM "admin_users" WHERE "admin_users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "admin_users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendering /usr/local/bundle/gems/activeadmin-2.7.0views/active_admin/resource/index.html.arb
   (0.6ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT  1 AS one FROM "branches" LIMIT $1 OFFSET $2) subquery_for_count  [["LIMIT", 30], ["OFFSET", 0]]
  CACHE  (0.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT  1 AS one FROM "branches" LIMIT $1 OFFSET $2) subquery_for_count  [["LIMIT", 30], ["OFFSET", 0]]
   (0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "branches"
  CACHE  (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT  1 AS one FROM "branches" LIMIT $1 OFFSET $2) subquery_for_count  [["LIMIT", 30], ["OFFSET", 0]]
  Branch Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "branches".* FROM "branches" ORDER BY "branches"."id" desc LIMIT $1 OFFSET $2  [["LIMIT", 30], ["OFFSET", 0]]
  Store Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "stores".* FROM "stores" WHERE "stores"."id" IN ($1, $2, $3)  [["id", 21], ["id", 1], ["id", 2]]
  BranchPhone Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "branch_phones".* FROM "branch_phones" WHERE "branch_phones"."branch_id" IN ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11)  [["branch_id", 25], ["branch_id", 24], ["branch_id", 22], ["branch_id", 20], ["branch_id", 19], ["branch_id", 14], ["branch_id", 11], ["branch_id", 4], ["branch_id", 3], ["branch_id", 2], ["branch_id", 1]]
  BranchPhone Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "branch_phones".* FROM "branch_phones" WHERE "branch_phones"."branch_id" = $1 ORDER BY "branch_phones"."created_at" ASC LIMIT $2  [["branch_id", 25], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  BranchPhone Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "branch_phones".* FROM "branch_phones" WHERE "branch_phones"."branch_id" = $1 ORDER BY "branch_phones"."created_at" ASC LIMIT $2  [["branch_id", 24], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  BranchPhone Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "branch_phones".* FROM "branch_phones" WHERE "branch_phones"."branch_id" = $1 ORDER BY "branch_phones"."created_at" ASC LIMIT $2  [["branch_id", 22], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  BranchPhone Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "branch_phones".* FROM "branch_phones" WHERE "branch_phones"."branch_id" = $1 ORDER BY "branch_phones"."created_at" ASC LIMIT $2  [["branch_id", 20], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  BranchPhone Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "branch_phones".* FROM "branch_phones" WHERE "branch_phones"."branch_id" = $1 ORDER BY "branch_phones"."created_at" ASC LIMIT $2  [["branch_id", 19], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  BranchPhone Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "branch_phones".* FROM "branch_phones" WHERE "branch_phones"."branch_id" = $1 ORDER BY "branch_phones"."created_at" ASC LIMIT $2  [["branch_id", 14], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  BranchPhone Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "branch_phones".* FROM "branch_phones" WHERE "branch_phones"."branch_id" = $1 ORDER BY "branch_phones"."created_at" ASC LIMIT $2  [["branch_id", 11], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  BranchPhone Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "branch_phones".* FROM "branch_phones" WHERE "branch_phones"."branch_id" = $1 ORDER BY "branch_phones"."created_at" ASC LIMIT $2  [["branch_id", 4], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  BranchPhone Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "branch_phones".* FROM "branch_phones" WHERE "branch_phones"."branch_id" = $1 ORDER BY "branch_phones"."created_at" ASC LIMIT $2  [["branch_id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  BranchPhone Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "branch_phones".* FROM "branch_phones" WHERE "branch_phones"."branch_id" = $1 ORDER BY "branch_phones"."created_at" ASC LIMIT $2  [["branch_id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  BranchPhone Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "branch_phones".* FROM "branch_phones" WHERE "branch_phones"."branch_id" = $1 ORDER BY "branch_phones"."created_at" ASC LIMIT $2  [["branch_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendered /usr/local/bundle/gems/activeadmin-2.7.0views/active_admin/resource/index.html.arb (219.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 258ms (Views: 208.7ms | ActiveRecord: 23.2ms)
```

so, any solutions to eliminate the n+1 query for the branch phone ?
knowing that I tried to eliminate it using controller actions like this
[image]

but still the branch phones N+1 query not solved

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting (N+1) query because you are ordering `branch_phones`. By default Rails returns records in assenting order. You don't have to order again.

I believe you have some association like bellow:

```
# app/models/branch.rb

class Branch < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :branch_phones
end
```

```
# app/models/branch_phone.rb

class BranchPhone < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :branch
end
```

Please add this lines in your `app/admin/brach.rb` file.

```
# app/admin/brach.rb

controller do
  def scoped_collection
    super.includes(:branch_phones)
  end
end

index do
  column :id
  column :manager_name
  column :manager_email
  column :phone_number do |branch|
    branch.branch_phones.first&.phone_number
  end

  actions
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Now the [includes](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/gregbell/active_admin/ActiveAdmin/Resource/Includes) method is available inside the ActiveAdmin. All you need to do is add this into the desired admin file.

```
# app/admin/brach.rb
ActiveAdmin.register Branch do

  includes :branch_phones

  index do
    column :id
    column :manager_name
    column :manager_email
    column :phone_number do |branch|
      branch&.branch_phones&.order(created_at: :asc)&.first&.phone_number
    end
    actions
  end
end
```